# Работа с DataGridView

Tags: c#, математика, datagridview

В DataGridView1 созданы столбцы к примеру

```
1 2 5 7 5
2 5 8 3 2
5 6 7 8 9
```

нужно выполнить математический расчёт на примере ниже
(S в формуле - это заданная int S)

```
richTextBox1.Text = "Ni="+ (dataGridView1[2,3] - dataGridView1[2,2]) * S;
richTextBox1.Text = "Ni="+ (dataGridView1[2,4] - dataGridView1[2,3]) * S;
```

но при этом же, самый первый пример должен быть на подобии такого

```
richTextBox1.Text = "Ni="+ (dataGridView1[2,1] - 0) * S;
```

(только надо сделать так, чтоб я в ручную не вводил эти строички кода для каждой операции, ибо строичек таких больше 5к должно быть)

Comment: richTextBox1 - это разные контролы на самом дела? Иначе содержимое будет просто перезатираться...

Comment: richtextbox1 по сути временная (я планировал через .lines[i] делать), но можно использовать любой другой инструмент, к примеру DataGridView2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто проходим в цикле по строкам грида:

```
richTextBox.Text = "Ni=" + ((int)dataGridView[2, 0].Value - 0) * S + Environment.NewLine;

for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    richTextBox.Text += "Ni=" + ((int)dataGridView[2, i].Value - (int)dataGridView[2, i - 1].Value) * S + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Нумерация строк и колонок начинается с нуля, а не единицы.

Чтобы получить значение из ячейки, используем свойство `Value`. Это свойство имеет тип `object`, поэтому его нужно скастовать (привести) к нужному типу. Я предположил, что это `int`.

При занесении данных в текстбокс используем оператор `+=` и в конце добавляем перенос строки `Environment.NewLine`.